# Where can I find a dataset of voice phishing attacks? Or scam phone call logs?

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, finance, audio, bank

I am conducting researches into a voice phishing attacks/scam phone call detection system using machine learning. However, I am facing difficulties finding an open dataset of voice phishing or phone calls logs I could work with.

Please, can anyone guide me to any related dataset? Or even suggestions on how to create such a dataset and deal with voice phishing?

Any opinions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to **voice spoofing**, which can be part of the phishing process. In the context of voice, the term spoofing is more common in literature. Spoofing/ phishing can take various forms either by using a replayed audio (if only a password is required for example) or an advanced voice synthesis/cloning system etc. Therefore the datasets can differ in their structure depending on the research specifications. The following are some datasets used in anti-spoofing research:

- [Voice Spoofing Detection Corpus (VSDC)](http://www.secs.oakland.edu/~mahmood/datasets/audiospoof.html)
- [avspoof](https://www.idiap.ch/dataset/avspoof)
- [H-Voice: Fake voice histograms (Imitation+DeepVoice)](https://data.mendeley.com/datasets/k47yd3m28w/4#folder-34f38bf6-6c0c-4a68-aca2-52f4f9dbac84)

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply.

Actually, the type of dataset I was looking for was the call detail record (CDR) enabling the program to detect if a call is genuine or a scam. After check around it turned out that they are really difficult to get from Telecom operator because of privacy concerns. So I had to find an alternative for the project.

I will use the given link about spoofing for further research.

Thank you.